# os.walk-ing through a directory structure to read many CSV headers and write them to an output CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder that contains 60 folders, each of which contains about 60 CSVs (and 1 or 2 non-CSVs).

I need to compare the header rows of all of these CSVs, so I am trying to go through the directories and write to an output CSV (1) the filepath of the file in question and (2) the header row in the subsequent cells in the row in the output CSV.

Then go to the next file, and write the same information in the next row of the output CSV.

I am lost in the part where I am writing the header rows to the CSV -- and am too lost to have even generated an error message.

Can anyone advise on what to do next?

```
import os
import sys
import csv

csvfile = '/Users/username/Documents/output.csv'

def main(args):

    # Open a CSV for writing outputs to
    with open(csvfile, 'w') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='\n')

        # Walk through the directory specified in cmd line
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
            for item in files:
                # Check if the item is a CSV
                if item.endswith('.csv'):
                    # If yes, read the first row
                    with open(item, newline='') as f:
                        reader = csv.reader(f)
                        row1 = next(reader)
                        # Write the first cell as the file name
                        f.write(os.path.realpath(item))
                        f.write(f.readline())
                        f.write('\n')
                        # Write this row to a new line in the csvfile var
                            # Go to next file

                # If not a CSV, go to next file
                else:
                    continue

                # Write each file to the CSV
                # writer.writerow([item])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting confused between which file you're reading and writing to. Confusion is normal when you try to do everything in one big function. The whole point of functions is to break things down so it's easy to follow, understand and debug.

Here is some code, which doesn't work, but you can easily print out what each function is returning, and once you know that's correct, you feed it to the next function. Each function is small, with very few variables, so not much can go wrong.

And most importantly, the variables in each function are local to it, meaning they cannot interfere with what's happening elsewhere, or even confuse you into thinking they might be interfering (and that makes a huge difference).

```
def collect_csv_data():
    results = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                headers = extract_headers(os.path.join(root, file))
                results.append((file, headers))
    return results

def extract_headers(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = reader.next()
    return headers

def write_results(result, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for result in results:
            writer.writerow(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    results = collect_csv_data(directory)
    write_results(results, 'results.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need a new csv file with 2 columns: file_path and headers.
If the header that you need is just a list of column names from that csv, then it will be easier if you use a `pandas` dataframe to store these values first and then write the dataframe to a csv.

```
import pandas as pd

res = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
    for item in files:
        # Check if the item is a CSV
        if item.endswith('.csv'):
            # If yes, read the first row
            df = pd.read_csv(item)
            row = {}
            row['file_path'] = os.path.realpath(item)
            row['headers'] = df.columns
            res.append(row)
res_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
res_df.to_csv(csvfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- but I'm actually looking for 1 column with file_path followed by a variable number of columns.  Basically, I want each column header to appear in a different column in the output.csv